# JSF 1.2 form, on hitting submit nothing gets rendered

Tags: html, jsf

On hitting submit nothing gets rendered. I think because of all the `<div>` tags that I have. Am I missing some `<h:form>` tags? Do I have to give the `<h:form>` tag for every div tag I have?

```
<f:view>

    <body>

    <h:form id="mainform" onkeypress="enterForm()">

            <div id="header">
            <center>
                <h1><span id="lblPageTitle" class="PrimaryTitle">Question</span><span class="gray">Administration</span></h1>
                <hr id="titlehr"></hr>
            </center>


            </div> 

        <div  id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li id="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Archives</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Downloads</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>     
            </ul>
        </div>  

        <div id="content-wrap">

            <div id="sidebar" align="left">

                <h1>Sidebar Menu</h1>
                <div class="left-box">
                    <ul class="sidemenu">               
                        <li><a href="AddQuestion.jsp">Add Question</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ModiftQuestion.jsp">Modify Question</a></li>
                        <li><a href="RemoveQuestion.jsp">Remove Question</a></li>

                    </ul>   
                </div>
        </div>

            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" valign="baseline" width="200"><h:outputLabel
                                        for="name" value="First Name:" /></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="baseline"><h:inputText id="name"
                                        value="#{addQuestionBean.fname }" >

                                        </h:inputText>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td align="right" valign="baseline" width="200"><h:outputLabel
                                        for="lname" value="Last Name:" /></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="baseline"><h:inputText id="lname"
                                        value="#{addQuestionBean.lname }" >

                                        </h:inputText>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>    
                                <td align="right" valign="baseline" width="200"><h:outputLabel
                                        for="ssn" value="Social Security:" /></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="baseline"><h:inputText id="ssn"
                                        value="#{addQuestionBean.ssn }" >

                                        </h:inputText>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>    
                                <td align="right" valign="baseline" width="200"><h:outputLabel
                                        for="mail" value="Email:" /></td>
                                <td align="left" valign="baseline">
                                <h:inputText id="mail" value="#{addQuestionBean.email}" required="true">
                                <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
                                </h:inputText>
                                </td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>
                        <br>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>  

            <br>    
                <TABLE width="100%">

                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                        <td align="center"><center><h:commandButton type="submit" id="SUBMIT"
                                value="SUBMIT" styleClass="commandButton"
                                action="#{addQuestionBean.doSubmit }">

                            </h:commandButton> <h:commandButton id="CANCEL" value="CANCEL"
                                action="#{addQuestionBean.doCancel }" type="submit">

                            </h:commandButton></center></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>

                </TABLE>

        </h:form>

        <center><b><jsp:include page="footer.jsp" flush="true"></jsp:include></b></center>


    </body>

</f:view>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *nothing gets rendered*? Is your action method being invoked? If so, is it performing the navigation rule or not?

Comment: Check what is happening when you call doSubmit in your managed bean , it should redirect to the page you want to visit next. If you return null or void then it will stay on the same page. Please give your backing bean snippet to understand it clearly.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you're using JSF 1.2 and not 1.1 or 1.0? Plain HTML is namely not directly supported in JSF 1.1/1.0.